# Анимация перелистывания страниц в android

Tags: android, анимация

Создание читалку книг в android. Столкнулся с тем, что не могу понять, каким образом реализовать анимацию перелистывания страниц.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что для этого требуется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что подразумевается работа за автора.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это ссылку. Думаю, это то, что надо: https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl